# php SESSION help

Tags: php

I need to display a logged in user's name. but I ahve a problem in doing

so.

```
"You have been successfully logged in as <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.&nbsp"
```

But the username seems to appear blank.. i merely get **logged in as .** .

Comment: Are you sure that you actually set the 'username' session variable?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using to set the value?

Comment: Not answerable without seeing more of your code. You need to make sure that session variable actually gets set. Also you need to use `session_start()` in every script instance

Comment: The session is set and is appearing elsewhere... I have made it such the above msg appears only if the session is set.. i use:  $_SESSION['username'] = $tmp;

Comment: @ineedhelp then this is a case for basic debugging. Walk through your code and verify (e.g. using test outputs) that the variables are set. We can't really help you with that, it's what every programmer has to do from time to time

Comment: I use: if(isset($_SESSION['username'])) echo $_SESSION['username']; exit(); .... I get the desired value.

Comment: @ineedhelp what is your question then?

Comment: i DON'T GET THE DESIRED OP IN THE ABOVE CASE

Comment: Are you unsetting the value in the same page? Try commenting this out - you may have an issue with variable scope. Also, try using a less generic session key (such as 'myapp_username') as 'username' might be being used else where in your system.

Comment: @Nick: nope... but works fine elsewhere

Comment: What is the above code exactly then? What is the complete code?

Comment: @ineedhelp in what context? A PHP file?

Comment: `error_reporting(-1)` at the top of your script.

Answer (score 2):

Did you…

- write the username into this actual variable?
- call `session_start()` when calling this page?

If yes, you might have to provide us with some more code.

Comment: The session is set and is appearing elsewhere... I have made it such the above msg appears only if the session is set.. i use: $_SESSION['username'] = $tmp;

Answer (score 0):

```
"You have been successfully logged in as <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.&nbsp"
```

**change to** (Try This)

```
echo "You have been successfully logged in as
$_SESSION['username'] &nbsp"
```

+++More

First of all you need to start the session with the `session_start()`function. Note that this function `should be  called before any output is generated!` This function initialise the $_SESSION superglobal array where you can store your data. So for example let's store user name in the session. You can do it as follows:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = 'ineedhelp';

"You have been successfully logged in as <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.&nbsp"
```

You have to make sure your session not `clean or destroy` in any block your code 
You have destroy with this line or not

```
//...more your code
unset($_SESSION['username']);//Check if you clean before output
"You have been successfully logged in as <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.&nbsp"
//...more your code
```

Chekc your `phpinfo()`

If you scroll down in the output you will find a complete section with session settings like this:

```
session
Session Support     enabled
Registered save handlers    files user
Registered serializer handlers  php php_binary wddx

Directive   Local Value     Master Value
session.auto_start  Off     Off
session.bug_compat_42   Off     Off
```

Comment: just echo $_SESSION['username']?

Comment: echo $_SESSION['username'];see what happend?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to peek into HTML page source? ;-)

you're trying to put PHP code inside of string contents.
Obviously it doesn't work.

```
echo "You have been successfully logged in as ".htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']).".&nbsp"
```

would work.

or you can make it like this

```
?>
You have been successfully logged in as 
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['username']); ?>.&nbsp
<?
```

Comment: I assume "working" means "there is `<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>` literally in the page source", yes? Doesn't it tell you something? :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, you must have `session_start()` on both pages, i.e. where you set and get `$_SESSION['username']` **before** you set or get them.

And also try `print_r($_SESSION)` (it will help debugging)  to check if `username` is set or not after `session_start` also check on logs if there is warning message.

Comment: @ineedhelp what you mean by it works, have you got your problem solved

Comment: @ineedhelp then you should add more of your code maybe then we can help or you have to do something similar or add your code to what is working